# Appending from one table to another then deleting/manipulating data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add from one table to another with .click and i got it to work

but now when i try to use the search field on the top table it clears the appended rows from the bottom table

I need to get these to start generating a table under it so that i can delete them all together

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#student-table2 tbody tr").click(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color", "#f4a941")
            .appendTo("#student-table3 tbody");

    });

    $("#student-table2").DataTable();
    $("body").on("click", "#student-table2 tbody tr", function(){
        $("#student-table3").data("stu-id", $(this).data("id"))
            .data("stu-name", $(this)
            .data("name"));

    });

    $("#access-table").DataTable();

    $(".datetimepicker").datetimepicker({
        format: 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss',
    });

});
```

Like i mentioned, it seems i can add the data to the table , but it wont store the row i select on table 2 when i use the search field atop the first table

I was thinking , maybe i can just have jquery generate the entire table with table placeholders already set in place? and not have it at all in HTML like i do, see under, i have student-table and student-table2 stacked

Here's my HTML

```
{% include "core/header.html" %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}

    <section class="ids-section form-section">

        <h2>{{ title }}</h2>
        <h2> All Students </h2>

        <table id="student-table2" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>School</th>
                    <th>License Plate</th>
                    <th>Active</th>
                    <th>Code</th>
                    <th>Added</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {% for stu in students %}
                    <tr data-id="{{ stu.id }}" data-name="{{ stu.name }}">
                        <td>{{ stu.name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ stu.school }}</td>
                        <td>{{ stu.license_plate }}</td>
                        <td>{{ stu.active }}</td>
                        <td>{{ stu.code }}</td>
                        <td>{{ stu.created }}</td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <h2> Selected for Delete </h2>
        <table id="students-table3" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>School</th>
                    <th>License Plate</th>
                    <th>Active</th>
                    <th>Code</th>
                    <th>Added</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                    <br>
                    <tr data-id="{{ stu.id }}" data-name="{{ stu.name }}">
                        <td>{{ stu.name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ stu.dealership }}</td>
                        <td>{{ stu.license_plate }}</td>
                        <td>{{ stu.active }}</td>
                        <td>{{ stu.code }}</td>
                        <td>{{ stu.created }}</td>
                    </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </section>


</div>

{% include "core/footer.html" %}
```

Comment: I figured out how to add from one table to the other, only porblem now is when i try to use the search field for the top table it clears both tables, i left the .click css so that i can see what i have selected

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that i actually was on the right track, i didnt know `.dataTables()` was a bootstrap marker for the tables so i simplified the remfunc.js file to

```
/* Main part- on click adds to second table           */

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#student-table2 tbody tr").click(function(){
    $(this).appendTo("#student-table3 tbody");

});
 /* Formats the table to coginate, 
    gives it an inputFilter and wraps it.
 */
$("#student-table2").DataTable();

});

$("#access-table").DataTable();

$(".datetimepicker").datetimepicker({
    format: 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss',
});
```

});

with and html file that looked like

```
{% include "core/header.html" %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}

    <section class="ids-section form-section">

        <h2>{{ title }}</h2>
        <h2> All Students </h2>

        <table id="student-table2" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>School</th>
                    <th>License Plate</th>
                    <th>Active</th>
                    <th>Code</th>
                    <th>Added</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {% for stu in students %}
                    <tr data-id="{{ stu.id }}" data-name="{{ stu.name }}">
                        <td>{{ stu.name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ stu.school }}</td>
                        <td>{{ stu.license_plate }}</td>
                        <td>{{ stu.active }}</td>
                        <td>{{ stu.code }}</td>
                        <td>{{ stu.created }}</td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <h2> Selected for Delete </h2>
        <table id="students-table3" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>School</th>
                    <th>License Plate</th>
                    <th>Active</th>
                    <th>Code</th>
                    <th>Added</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                    <br>
                    <tr data-id="{{ stu.id }}" data-name="{{ stu.name }}">
                        <td>{{ stu.name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ stu.dealership }}</td>
                        <td>{{ stu.license_plate }}</td>
                        <td>{{ stu.active }}</td>
                        <td>{{ stu.code }}</td>
                        <td>{{ stu.created }}</td>
                    </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </section>


</div>

{% include "core/footer.html" %}
```